# jqgrid deselectAfterSort for datatype json

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

While the caveat here should be "if it ain't broke, don't fix it", I want to ask this question anyway.

I have a jqGrid loading data from a web service returning JSON data.  my datatype is set as "json", and all is working well.  I needed to disable the "deselect" of a row after a sort was implemented.  I found the deselectAfterSort option in the wiki documentation, set the value to false, and all was working as expected.  However, the documentation says "Applicable only when we use datatype : local." [(wiki documentation here)](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions).

So this option worked as expected, but Im not using a local data type.  Am I doing this correctly?  I want to make sure whatever I do is supported and following proper implementation standards.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you use `loadonce: true` option which changes `datatype` from initial `"json"` value to `"local"` after the first loading of data from the server. So the option `deselectAfterSort: true` will work later during *local* sorting of the data loaded initially from the server.

Comment: You nailed it @Oleg - side note, all of your posts here on SO are incredibly helpful for using jqGrid, thanks so much for the effort.

Comment: @ewitkows: You are welcome! I'm glad that my old answers were helpful for you too.